# POST data to a Google script from Integromat

Tags: google-apps-script

I have create a google script that created Google Forms at the press of a button. But I am wondering if anyone can tell me how I could post the question data to the script from Integromat. Integromat has a HTTP- Make Request Module. That Sends HTTP requests to chosen URL, Images attached.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Script

```
 function createForm() {  
   // create & name Form  
   var item = "Speaker Information Form";  
   var form = FormApp.create(item)  
       .setTitle(item);  
   
   // single line text field  
   item = "Name, Title, Organization";  
   form.addTextItem()  
       .setTitle(item)  
       .setRequired(true);  
   
   // multi-line "text area"  
   item = "Short biography (4-6 sentences)";  
   form.addParagraphTextItem()  
       .setTitle(item)  
       .setRequired(true);  
   
   // radiobuttons  
   item = "Handout format";  
   var choices = ["1-Pager", "Stapled", "Soft copy (PDF)", "none"];  
   form.addMultipleChoiceItem()  
       .setTitle(item)  
       .setChoiceValues(choices)  
       .setRequired(true);  
   
   // (multiple choice) checkboxes  
   item = "Microphone preference (if any)";  
   choices = ["wireless/lapel", "handheld", "podium/stand"];  
   form.addCheckboxItem()  
       .setTitle(item)  
       .setChoiceValues(choices);  
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by starting your function with `doPost(e)` ( or `doGet(e)` ) and **deploy your script as webapplication**.

Make sure to return proper return using `ContentService` and collect what you want to use on your script from `e`.

Here is what I developed as a demo to other integromates with OpenWeather API.
Basic architecture is

1. recieving array of cities
2. returning array of weather forcasts

```
    const API_KEY = ScriptProperties.getProperty("API_KEY");
    const weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    
    function doPost(e) {
      //transforming request body to JSON
      let body = JSON.parse(e.postData.getDataAsString());
    
      //preparing output
      let output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
      output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    
      //verifying it contains access code
      if(!("access_code" in body)|"access_code" in body & body.access_code!=check ){
        var errresponse ={
          "status":"error",
          "msg":"You need an access code to have a proper rerurn"
        }
        output.setContent(JSON.stringify(errresponse));
        return output;
      };
      
      //Proceed to the rest if it contains code
      let cities = body.cities;
      
      let howmany = cities.length
      sheet.getRange(2,1,1,howmany).setValue([cities])//just making it visible
    
    
      let weathersarr = []
      for(city of cities){
        //Making API request
        let options ={
          "method":"get",
          "muteHttpExceptions":true
        }
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(weatherURL+city+"&appid="+API_KEY, options).getContentText();
        
        let data = JSON.parse(response)
        let primeWeather = data["weather"][0]["main"]
        weathersarr.push({"city":city, "weather":primeWeather})
      }
      
      let weathers = {"weathers":weathersarr}
    
      //returning response
      output.setContent(JSON.stringify(weathers));
      return output
    }
```